# Android Studio section_format wont work

Tags: android

Here is the screenshot of the code, I am new to programming and this app I am making is my school project, no experience working with Android studio before( a bit of Java but not too much)

http://prntscr.com/i465km

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
     TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
     textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
     return rootView;
}
```

So my question is, why is this section_format error and app is giving me two answers how to fix it: create string value or create field with the same name(section_format)?

Answer (score 1):

setText() method displays the string inside it. Like this

```
 textView.setText("Sample Text");
```

if you are displaying a message from a method it should return a string value

Like this

```
private string getString(param1 , param2){
//do something with parameters
return string;
}
```

Now you can get the message from the method like this:

```
textView.setText(getString(param1, param2))
```